# Erros when compiling biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

On my desktop I have a folder called `biblatex` containing two files I am working with: `biblatex.tex` and `biblatex.bib`. This should be my setup to become familiar with BibLaTeX. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with TeX Live 2013 installed. After compiling my files I got this error message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013) The top-level auxiliary file: biblatex.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file biblatex.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file biblatex.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file biblatex.aux (There were 3 error messages)
```

The files I copied as an example from the web are:

**biblatex.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex.bib}

\begin{document}

You can cite an online resource \cite{ford}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**biblatex.bib**

```
@online{ford,
    author = {Ford, Rebecca},
    title  = {Earthquake: Twitter Users Learned of Tremors Seconds Before Feeling Them},
    date   = {2011-08},
    url    = {http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/earthquake-twitter-users-learned-tremors-226481}
}
```

For my work I use Texmaker and the fast compile with `PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf`.

Comment: You need to compile your file with Biber if you specify `backend=biber`: `pdflatex test`, `biber test`, `pdflatex test`. See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations: TeXmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/35864). If you want to use BibbTeX as a backend instead (but remember: only Biber gives full access to all of `biblatex`'s features), specify `backend=bibtex` and not `backend=biber`.

Comment: Unfortunately Texmaker's `PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View Pdf` option is slightly misnamed, as you still have to manually choose `biber` as the BibTeX replacement, and BibLaTeX is not a programme that can be run on a file.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I configured my installation of Texmaker as it is described in your helpful link. After that I got the error message: `ERROR - Cannot find control file 'biblatex.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?`. I figured out that I have to run biber without adding the .tex or .aux extension to the file. Now everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly; but the post I linked to did not include the file extension in the configuration: `biber %` should do exactly what you want.